# prove, using induction that for natural $n$ and $0<x<1$ that $(1-x)^n<\frac{1}{1+nx}$

Tags: calculus, induction

How to prove, using induction, that for every natural $n$, and for every $0<x<1$ :$$(1-x)^n<\frac{1}{1+nx}$$

Comment: Are you familiar with [Bernoulli's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli%27s_inequality): $(1-x)^n>1+nx$?

Comment: yeah, its $(1+(-x))^n>1-nx$. But its bigger not smaller

Answer (score 1):

It is just a consequence of the [AM-GM inequality](http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/Arithmetic_Mean-Geometric_Mean_Inequality), since $x\in (0,1)$ grants:

$$ (1-x)^n (1+nx) \color{red}{\leq} \left(\frac{n\cdot(1-x)+(1+nx)}{n+1}\right)^{n+1}=1 $$
but equality is achieved only when $(1-x)=(1+nx)$, i.e. at $x=0$.

Answer (score 1):

It is not really hard: suppose by the inductive hypothesis that, for some $n$, we have $\;(1-x)^n<\dfrac{1}{1+nx}$. As $0<1-x<1$, multiplying both sides by $1-x$, we get
$$(1-x)^{n+1}<\dfrac{1-x}{1+nx}$$
so it is enough to prove $\;\dfrac{1-x}{1+nx}\le\dfrac1{1+(n+1)x}$. As all numbers are positive, this amounts to proving
$$(1-x)\bigl(1+(n+1)x\bigr)\le 1+nx\iff 1+nx-(n+1)x^2\le1+nx. $$

Comment: The base case needs to be established as well. Also not hard - proving $1-x < \frac{1}{1+x}$ amounts to proving $(1-x)(1+x)<1$, similar to the inductive step.

Comment: Of course. I didn't claim it's a full proof, which is not in the spirit ogf this site. Note the strict inequality is true only for $n\ge 1$ natural numbers, for me, begin at $0$).

Comment: It was less a critique of your answer than a note for the OP who may forget that the base case needs to be established.